# Installing dmg through terminal results in unverified signature macOS

Tags: bash, macos, unix, dmg, .app

I was trying to automate .dmg installation on MacOS 14.2.1 through a bash script
The script does this:

1. mount the .dmg
2. copy the .app inside the .dmg into /Applications
3. unmount the .dmg

After the .app is copied to /Applications, when I try to open it it displays “cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified".
However when I install it manually without a script it doesn't show this message.
Important note: The application I was testing this on was Discord, so it's definitely signed and verified

This is the script

```
#/bin/sh

hdiutil attach ~/Downloads/Discord.dmg -quiet -nobrowse
cp -rf /Volumes/Discord/Discord.app /Applications
hdiutil detach /Volumes/Discord
```

One thing I noticed is that if I move the .app through the script (not manually) and try to verify its signature with `codesign --verify /Applications/Discord.app` It displays:

```
/Applications/Discord.app: bundle format is ambiguous (could be app or framework)
In subcomponent: /Applications/Discord.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
rm -rf /Applications/Discord.app
cp -R /Volumes/Discord/Discord.app /Applications
```

From `man cp`:

> Historic versions of the cp utility had a -r option.  This
> implementation supports that option, however, its behavior
> is different from historical FreeBSD behavior.  Use of this option is strongly discouraged as the behavior is
> implementation-dependent.